# Infinite loop after asking for user Input

Tags: java, loops

I am a high school student enrolled in a Computer Science course. We were recently assigned this project:

*"Implement a combination lock class. A combinationlock has a dial with 26 positions labeled A.....Z. The dial needsto be set three times. if it is set to the correct combination, the lock can be opened. When the lock is closed again, the combination can be entered again. if a user sets the dial more than three times, he last three settings detemine whether the lock can be opened. An important part of this exercise is to implement asuitable interface for the CombinationLockclass."*

I have everything completed and running correctly except that I'm having issues with the part where if the lock is closed, the combination can be opened again. We haven't learned about loops yet, but I remember my teacher mentioning them once and I figured that using loops could be a solution to my problem. I looked ahead in the book, and I tried to use a loop as part of my answer. However, I think i ended up with an infinite loop, and I do not know how to fix the problem. Is there a way, other than using a loop, to do this?

My Tester class is as follows:

```
public class CombinationLockTester

{

public static void main(String [] args)

{   
    System.out.println("*All other questions are answered with Yes or No.");
    Scanner kin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter what you want the combination to be. (All uppercase, with no space seperation) : ");
    String userCode = kin.next();

    CombinationLock userCombination = new CombinationLock(userCode);

    System.out.print("Try to open the lock? : " );
    String tryToOpenLockYesNo = kin.next();

    if (tryToOpenLockYesNo.equals("Yes")) 
    {

        System.out.print("Enter the lock Combination : " );
        String userCombinationLockGuess = kin.next();

        userCombination.openLock(userCombinationLockGuess);
        if (userCombinationLockGuess.equals(userCode))
        {

            System.out.print("Correct Combination! Open the Lock? : ");
            String openLockYesNo = kin.next();

            if (openLockYesNo.equals("Yes")) 
            {
                userCombination.unlock();

                System.out.print("The lock is open and you have reaped the rewards of its contents. Will you now close the lock? : ");
                String closeLockYesNo = kin.next();

                if (closeLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                {
                    userCombination.lock();
                    ;
                    System.out.print("The lock is now closed again. Will you check again to see if you closed it? : ");
                    String checkLockYesNo = kin.next();

                    if (checkLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("The lock is locked: " + userCombination.isItClosed());

                        System.out.print("Re-enter the combination? : " );
                        String restartYesNo = kin.next();

                        if (restartYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                        {
                            do
                            {
                                if (tryToOpenLockYesNo.equals("Yes")) 
                                {

                                    System.out.print("Enter the lock Combination : " );
                                    String userCombinationLockGuess2 = kin.next();

                                    userCombination.openLock(userCombinationLockGuess2);
                                    if (userCombinationLockGuess2.equals(userCode))
                                    {

                                        System.out.print("Correct Combination! Open the Lock? : ");
                                        String openLockYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                        if (openLockYesNo2.equals("Yes")) 
                                        {
                                            userCombination.unlock();

                                            System.out.print("The lock is open and you have reaped the rewards of its contents. Will you now close the lock? : ");
                                            String closeLockYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                            if (closeLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                                            {
                                                userCombination.lock();

                                                System.out.print("The lock is now closed again. Will you check again to see if you closed it? : ");
                                                String checkLockYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                                if (checkLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("The lock is locked: " + userCombination.isItClosed());

                                                    System.out.print("Re-enter the combination? : " );
                                                    String restartYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                                    if (restartYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                                                    {
                                                        System.out.println("");
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    { 
                                                        System.out.println("Goodbye." );
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("You did not check to see if the lock is open." );
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                System.out.print("You have left the lock open and unlocked.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("The lock is unlocked, but you chose not to open it. Are you afraid to face what's inside?");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Incorrect combination!");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("The secret of the combination lock will always remain a mystery to you...");
                                }
                            }

                            while (userCombination.isItClosed() == true);
                        }
                        else
                        { 
                            System.out.println("Goodbye." );
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("You did not check to see if the lock is open." );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("You have left the lock open and unlocked.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The lock is unlocked, but you chose not to open it. Are you afraid to face what's inside?");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect combination!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The secret of the combination lock will always remain a mystery to you...");
    }

}
```

And the class itself is:

```
public class CombinationLock
{

private String code;
private String userGuess;
private boolean isLockClosed;

public CombinationLock(String pCode)
{
    code = pCode;
    isLockClosed = true;
}

public void openLock(String pUserGuess)
{
    userGuess = pUserGuess;

    if (userGuess.length() > 3)
    {
        userGuess = userGuess.substring(userGuess.length() - 3, userGuess.length());
    }
    else
    {
        userGuess = userGuess;
    }

}


public void unlock()
{
    if (userGuess.equals(code))
        isLockClosed = false;
}

public void lock()
{
    isLockClosed = true;
    userGuess = "";
}

public boolean isItClosed()
{
    return isLockClosed;
}
}
```

Comment: Note that `isItClosed()` returns a `boolean`, therefore `userCombination.isItClosed() == true` is redundant; 
`while (userCombination.isItClosed())` is preferred.

Comment: I can't think of a way to do this without a loop, but it does seem weird that you've been set this if you haven't learnt about loops yet. Putting print statements in your program everywhere where there's an if/else or do to make sure it's doing what it's supposed to (which it's not) should reveal where it's going wrong. +1 for compilable code.

Answer (score 0):

The layout of your program is very clear, but upon running it, if the user enters the combination, then makes a guess which is wrong, the program stops. There should be a do while loop higher up than the one you have so that in the event described, the user is asked if they want to make another guess.

When should the program end though? When they make 3 wrong guesses or when the user says they want it to end or both? These questions need to be answered and the program modified accordingly if necessary. It looks good though. You should be able to make it work having come this far.

Also, bear in mind that you can use

```
break;
```

to break out of loops if you need to.

You should also close the Scanner when you've finished with it as follows:

```
kin.close();
```

Making the following few modifications to your CombinationLockTester class produces the desired results:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CombinationLockTester

{

public static void main(String [] args)

{   
    System.out.println("*All other questions are answered with Yes or No.");
    Scanner kin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter what you want the combination to be. (All uppercase, with no space seperation) : ");
    String userCode = kin.next();

    CombinationLock userCombination = new CombinationLock(userCode);

    do
    {

    System.out.print("Try to open the lock? : " );
    String tryToOpenLockYesNo = kin.next();

    if (tryToOpenLockYesNo.equals("Yes")) 
    {

        System.out.print("Enter the lock Combination : " );
        String userCombinationLockGuess = kin.next();

        userCombination.openLock(userCombinationLockGuess);
        if (userCombinationLockGuess.equals(userCode))
        {

            System.out.print("Correct Combination! Open the Lock? : ");
            String openLockYesNo = kin.next();

            if (openLockYesNo.equals("Yes")) 
            {
                userCombination.unlock();

                System.out.print("The lock is open and you have reaped the rewards of its contents. Will you now close the lock? : ");
                String closeLockYesNo = kin.next();

                if (closeLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                {
                    userCombination.lock();
                    ;
                    System.out.print("The lock is now closed again. Will you check again to see if you closed it? : ");
                    String checkLockYesNo = kin.next();

                    if (checkLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("The lock is locked: " + userCombination.isItClosed());

                        System.out.print("Re-enter the combination? : " );
                        String restartYesNo = kin.next();

                        if (restartYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                        {

                                if (tryToOpenLockYesNo.equals("Yes")) 
                                {

                                    System.out.print("Enter the lock Combination : " );
                                    String userCombinationLockGuess2 = kin.next();

                                    userCombination.openLock(userCombinationLockGuess2);
                                    if (userCombinationLockGuess2.equals(userCode))
                                    {

                                        System.out.print("Correct Combination! Open the Lock? : ");
                                        String openLockYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                        if (openLockYesNo2.equals("Yes")) 
                                        {
                                            userCombination.unlock();

                                            System.out.print("The lock is open and you have reaped the rewards of its contents. Will you now close the lock? : ");
                                            String closeLockYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                            if (closeLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                                            {
                                                userCombination.lock();

                                                System.out.print("The lock is now closed again. Will you check again to see if you closed it? : ");
                                                String checkLockYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                                if (checkLockYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("The lock is locked: " + userCombination.isItClosed());

                                                    System.out.print("Re-enter the combination? : " );
                                                    String restartYesNo2 = kin.next();

                                                    if (restartYesNo.equals("Yes"))
                                                    {
                                                        System.out.println("");
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    { 
                                                        System.out.println("Goodbye." );
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    System.out.println("You did not check to see if the lock is open." );
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                System.out.print("You have left the lock open and unlocked.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("The lock is unlocked, but you chose not to open it. Are you afraid to face what's inside?");
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Incorrect combination!");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    System.out.println("The secret of the combination lock will always remain a mystery to you...");
                                    break;
                                }

                        }
                        else
                        { 
                            System.out.println("Goodbye." );
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("You did not check to see if the lock is open." );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print("You have left the lock open and unlocked.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The lock is unlocked, but you chose not to open it. Are you afraid to face what's inside?");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect combination!");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("The secret of the combination lock will always remain a mystery to you...");
        break;
    }

    }

    while (userCombination.isItClosed() == true);

    kin.close();

}

}
```

The only other improvement needed is to prevent the user from having any more goes at opening the lock if they get it wrong 3 times in a row by adding an int counter which gets incremented every time they get it wrong (count++) and then another if statement at the right place along the line of

```
if(count==3) 
{

    print "no more tries allowed"
    break;

}

else

{

   //do nothing

}
```

The else part isn't actually needed, as nothing is done in it.

Comment: The entire second guess could be rolled up into a single do while considering it's the same.

Comment: Do you mean only one do loop is needed in the program?

Comment: Yes, the second part is an exact copy, prompts and all, of the first user interaction.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. +1's for helpful info.